# how to read a property from JSON object in python, this property is stored in a variable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So, lets say I have a JSON object stored in the variable names `jsonobject` and want to read a specific property from it, lets say `address.state`. If I say `jsonobject.address.state` I am getting the expected output, but what if the property that I am trying to fins i.e. `address.state` is stored in a variable lets say `key`. 
So `key = "address.state"` and when I try to get jsonobject.key I get an error saying `jsonobject has no property names key.`
How can I implement this .

```
    def main():
            #messagebody='{"name":"vivke",  "age":"26", "comname":"Infracloud", "address":{ "street":44, "state":"NY" } }'
            #i am HTTP POSTing above message format to the function
            messagebody = request.get_data().decode("utf-8")
            key = "address.state"
            #convert messagebody to JSON
            jsondata = jsonparser.json2obj(messagebody)
            return jsondata.address.state # this works file
            return jsondata.key #isnt working
```

here is the code of jsonparser

```
import json
from collections import namedtuple

def _json_object_hook(d): return namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values())
def json2obj(data): return json.loads(data, object_hook=_json_object_hook)
```

Comment: Show us the code, that's what we normally *eat* around here.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: In general you use dictionary syntax for interacting with JSON objects in python - especially if they've been unpacked by the `json` module from the standard library. So instead of `jsonobject.address.state`, do `jsonobject['address']['state']`. We'll be able to give more targeted advice if you provide a sample of your code and an example of the JSON you want to parse.

Comment: What are `request` and `jsonparser.json2obj` ? They don't seem standard python functions.

Comment: added the complete code @PedroLobito

Comment: key here is a local variable assigned to a string and when you do jsondata.key then you are trying to access a member / attribute named key from jsondata. it will not magically replace every reference to key with the string value.

Comment: @Luv I totally agree with you, but is there a way to implement this.

Comment: It is not trivial, I believe you can derive a new type from dict and then override the getattr method to achieve this result. you could check implementation of https://pypi.org/project/python-box/ to know how to do that but I think your requirement is simpler and you should just split the string at "." and then use dictionary.get with string for each split element.

Answer (score 0):

The key in jsondata.key is the name of the attribute. Under the hood, something like `jsondata.__getattr__("key")`. It has nothing to do with your `key = "address.state"`.

If you insist on it, you may need to override the `__getattr__` function to split the "address.state" and call the superclass's `__getattr__` recursively.